# C# .NET 3.0/3.5 features in 2.0 using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

What are some of the new features that can be used in .NET 2.0 that are specific to C# 3.0/3.5 after upgrading to Visual Studio 2008? Also, what are some of the features that aren't available?

**Available**

- Lambdas
- Extension methods (by declaring an empty System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute)
- Automatic properties
- Object initializers
- Collection Initializers
- LINQ to Objects (by implementing IEnumerable extension methods, see [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx))

**Not Available**

- Expression trees
- WPF/Silverlight Libraries

Comment: Expression trees are available through the use of Mono. See my answer below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use any new C# 3.0 feature that is handled by the compiler by emitting 2.0-compatible IL and doesn't reference any of the new 3.5 assemblies:

- Lambdas (used as `Func<..>`, not `Expression<Func<..>>` )
- Extension methods (by declaring an empty `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute`)
- Automatic properties
- Object Initializers
- Collection Initializers
- LINQ to Objects (by implementing `IEnumerable<T>` extension methods, see [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx))

Answer (score 5):

Pretty much everything! Daniel Moth covers this [here](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2007/05/using-c-30-from-net-20.html) and [here](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2007/05/using-extension-methods-in-fx-20.html). That only leaves runtime support: LINQ-to-Objects is provided by [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) - which leaves just bigger APIs like Expression support, and tools like LINQ-to-SQL. These are too big to be reasonably ported back to .NET 2.0, so I'd use .NET 3.5 for these.

Answer (score 5):

I cover this in an [article on my site](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx).

Almost all C# 3.0 features are available when targeting .NET 2.0. For extension methods, you need to define an extra attribute. Expression trees aren't available at all. Query expression support is based on a translation followed by "normal" C# rules, so you'll need something to provide the Select, Where etc methods. [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) is the de facto standard "LINQ to Objects in .NET 2.0" implementation. You may well want to declare the delegates in the `Func` and `Action` delegate families to make it easier to work with lambda expressions - and then remove them if/when you move to .NET 3.5

Answer (score 3):

To define extension methods, you'll need to supply the following class if you're targeting .NET 2.0:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices {
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
    sealed class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute { }
}
```

Comment: I also had to do this (found you suggesting this on another site) to be able to use Ninject 1.0 for 2.0 in a 3.5 SP1 project. Very wierd...

Answer (score 2):

There was a previous discussion about something similar you may also want to read too:

[Targeting .NET Framework 3.5, Using .NET 2.0 Runtime. Caveats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140239/targeting-net-framework-35-using-net-20-runtime-caveats)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mono's version of the System.Core which fully supports LINQ & Expression Trees.
I compiled its source against .net 2.0, and now I can use it in my .net2.0 projects.
This is great for projects that needs to be deployed on win2k, where .net3.5 is not available.

Comment: do these expression trees require .Net 2.0 SP1?

Comment: nope. plain old .NET 2.0. Works great even on win2k machines.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas & Extension methods are handled purely by the compiler and can be used with the .Net 2.0 framework.

Comment: Lambdas as delegates, yes. But lambdas as Expressions rely on the Expression class(es) from .NET 3.5.