# How to use .NET 3.x features in .NET 2.0 (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2008, .net-2.0

You're stuck with targeting .NET 2.0 in Visual Studio 2008, but you'd like to use all the latest goodness from .NET 3.x features, like:

- LINQ
- Extension Methods
- Lambdas

What can one do to enable this awesomeness?

**EDIT:**  I had not originally found the post: [C# .NET 3.0/3.5 features in 2.0 using Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173080/c-net-3-0-3-5-features-in-2-0-using-visual-studio-2008).  Go there for an answer.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, it is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173080/c-net-3-0-3-5-features-in-2-0-using-visual-studio-2008

Comment: This can be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Brett, you can vote to close your own question if you wish :)

Comment: Moayad: I need two more votes to close it.  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to Use .NET 3.5 Features and C# 3.0 Syntax in .NET 2.0?](http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/12/23/how-to-use-net-35-features-and-c-30-syntax-in-net-20.html)

Also, at Stackoverflow: [C# .NET 3.0/3.5 features in 2.0 using Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173080/c-net-3-0-3-5-features-in-2-0-using-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 0):

.NET 3.x features are built upon 2.0. Have you tried adding System.Core as a reference?

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods and lambda expressions, at least, are available when targeting .NET 2.0 - see [C# .NET 3.0/3.5 features in 2.0 using Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173080/c-net-3-0-3-5-features-in-2-0-using-visual-studio-2008).

Answer (score -2):

Convince your employer to update and allow you to target 3.5. Other than that your out of luck i think,