# Is .net framework 2.0 required if 3.5 is installed?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

I'm wondering if .net framework 3.5 is installed, is .net framework 2.0 still required to run .net 2.0 applications? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Targeting .NET Framework 3.5, Using .NET 2.0 Runtime. Caveats?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140239/targeting-net-framework-3-5-using-net-2-0-runtime-caveats)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.Net 3.5 is really .Net 2.0 plus some extras.  You can't install 3.5 unless .Net 2.0 is also there.

Comment: Suppose .net framework 3.5 is installed on a brand new windows machine. Can I run .net 2.0 applications on that machine without installing .net framework 2.0 ?

Comment: Yes. If .NET 3.5 is there, then you can run something targeting .NET 2.0.

Comment: If you go look at the actual assemblies included with each, you'll notice 3.5 does not even have many such as mscorlib.dll. (Path: `%windir%/Microsoft.NET/Framework/`)

Answer (score 2):

.NET 3.5 runs on top of .NET 2.0, so they both have be there to use .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I beg to differ.  I'm trying to install Email2DB 3.0 on a Windows Server 2003 machine that has .Net 3.5 and the installation errors out saying it can't find .Net 2.0.  Tech support's only reply to my issue is "You have to have .Net 2.0 installed because it has certain components required."  With that said, however, their manual says with Server 2008 or 2012 it requires .Net 3.5 so I'm sure the issue is with the software being installed.