# How to generate installation requirements for my program?

Tags: c#, .net, installation

I have a program in C# that was developed on a PC that has several of installed .NET frameworks, Service Packs, etc. How can I understand what are the minimal installation requirements in order to distribute the program to users? Should I start with a clean PC and test one-by-one .NET frameworks or is there a better approach?

Comment: What version of .NET is your app targeting?

Comment: @DaveZych, I know, It sounds strange, but I am not sure what version it is targeting. I remember that it was very difficult to setup the environment to start developing and make it work on my PC, and after that I didn't want to make any changes. Can you advise how to check what you ask?

Comment: @Serg did you need more? do you have another question?

Comment: @paqogomez, no, thanks. I used the answers here, and partially found myself "how to MAKE it be supported" by different .NET versions (using `app.config` file). I will accept one of the answers tomorrow. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looking at the .NET version that your application is targeting.

If for example, you are targeting .NET 3.5 you will need to [also include .NET 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690658/is-net-framework-2-0-required-if-3-5-is-installed)

.NET 4.0 and 4.5 are self contained, so including earlier versions is not necessary for them.

You can check the version that you are targeting by going to the properties of your project (right click, properties in the solution explorer), clicking on the `Build` tab and looking for `Target Framework`

[Microsoft recommends that you look for features that your application requires](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the operating systems rather than look for which version of Windows you are targeting.  So its better to list those out and tackle them one by one.  I find this to be a bit overkill sometimes, but it does help once you get to logo certification.

Answer (score 1):

check Target Framework in your Project Properties

Note :- Step for open project Solution 
(Open Your Project in Visual Studio and then open solution explorer and Right click on Properties)

Some link to more Help you

1 : [Retrieve Target Framework Version and Target Framework Profile from a .Net Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854664/retrieve-target-framework-version-and-target-framework-profile-from-a-net-assem)

2 : [How to find the .NET framework version of a Visual Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231632/how-to-find-the-net-framework-version-of-a-visual-studio-project)